# Strip special characters out of text with PHP

Tags: php, rss

I have written a php program that generates rss feeds, however I am having difficulties with it because of special characters found in the text that is being populated in the feed. Is there a way to easily remove these special characters (like the `&` symbol) or is there another library that performs the same rss generating function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just sanitise the posts from the database before putting them in the feed?
You can easily use php's inbuilt `html_entities()` function.

eg:

```
$post = 'This came from the database and contains nasty characters like &!';
$sanitised = htmlentities($post);
```

Now `$sanitised` equals "This%20came%20from%20the%20database%20and%20contains%20nasty%20characters%20like%20%26!" which should display fine in any rss reader.

Comment: This almost worked. Now I see some characters like this ;€™s which is breaking my feed.

Any suggestions

Comment: I'd suggest going with your first instinct, and using a library.

Answer (score 2):

While encoding the data isn't really that hard, using a library to generate a good compatible RSS or Atom feed is probably a good solution (and, after all *is what you've asked for*).

[Zend_Feed](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.importing.html#zend.feed.importing.custom) provides feed *creation* in addition to feed *reading*.

Taken from the Zend_Feed documentation:

```
// importing a rss feed from an array
$feed = Zend_Feed::importArray($array, 'rss'); 

// dump the feed to standard output
print $feed->saveXML();

// send http headers and dump the feed
$feed->send();
```

As to availability on hosts, some may have the Zend Framework in their include directory. But if not, it's easy to just copy the Zend Framework libraries you need (in your case, the Zend_Feed files) someplace in your hosting directory.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

This applies to XML (RSS feeds are XML) as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using SimpleXMLElement to generate my RSS. It's crazy simple to use:

```
$elementA->nestedElementB->elementC['AttributeD'] = $str_value
```

And all the escaping and encoding is taken care of.